# How about the outside of the Garden of Eden?

Tags: adam, eden

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [From where did Cain get his wife?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/from-where-did-cain-get-his-wife)

Indirectly, even for a beginner it's clear that outside the Garden of Eden some people lived. One may find more things about this in the story of Abel and Cain. This is nonsense since Adam is supposed to be the first man ever. How is that possible?

Comment: Who was the wife of Cain (for instance) ?

Comment: Your questions need to show your research, I'm afraid. *Why* is it "clear"? What is "indirect"? I have some idea of what you're talking about, but you can help the answer by giving more detail in the question. Have you considered that God could have created other people? The Bible does not say that he didn't; it only mentions the characters important to the story.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: a possible explanation here is that Genesis (that part with Adam and Eve) represents the birth of the Jewish people. In fact, this was my answer I found when I was very young. Since then I haven't managed to find anything better.

Comment: Another possibility is that Adam and Eve had many children who are not named in scripture, and at that time brothers and sisters married (the Law banning that was introduced thousands of years later).

Comment: @Wikis: the 2 questions are related. The main question is "were there other people?". If there were other people then this explains where the Cain's wife comes from.

Comment: Thanks. Thinking more about it, I think this is a duplicate and therefore have voted to close. If four others agree (or one moderator), it will be closed.

Comment: @Wikis: what is its duplicate?

Comment: Normally, duplicates appear in a highlight in the question space. In this case it's [From where did Cain get his wife?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/from-where-did-cain-get-his-wife) -- as linked in [Wiki's comment](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/how-about-the-outside-of-the-garden-of-eden#comment28248_10071). Links are blue and not underlined.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: my main question is much more complex than that question. One cannot put the equal sign between them.

Comment: In that case, please expand it to make that clear. I refer you to my [first comment](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/how-about-the-outside-of-the-garden-of-eden#comment28243_10071).

Comment: This question need some work before it is reasonably answered. Please take advantage of our community in [chat] or here in comment to help you find a specific enough direction for this. One half of the question is completely unclear, so I could have closed this is "not a real question" because of the vague, broad nature and lack of references. Because the other half was a duplicate of a previous question, I have closed as a duplicate for now.

Comment: This doesn't mean you can fix this up and get it re-opened. Please check out the posts on our meta site [that give guidelines for questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/faq+questions) including the one about how to get closed questions re-opened. Once it is clear what the question is and it is scoped in a way that fits this site's guidelines, we can open it back up and people can go at it. But the question needs to be clear first.

Comment: Communication isn't just about you. What's in your head may be clear to you, but what we are saying as outside observers is that in reading your questions, there is not enough specific detail for them to be clear. We aren't treating everybody the same, we're responding to your questions individually based on their own current merits -- and encouraging you to improve them and giving you directions for that to happen. Insulting the people trying to help you isn't going to help your cause. There are a lot of experienced folks here that can help show you the ropes. Please listen to them.

Comment: This site isn't for helping people find truth. Answers  only represent Christianity in it's various forms. This is a place primarily for experts or those willing to do  background research to ask informed questions. _We are willing to help you with that, and lots of people have stepped up and offered their time and expertise to help you make them so._ Your questions aren't invalid, they just aren't a fit for this site without some more effort to give them scope or focus. And it's not just me, you've got half a dozen voices saying roughly the same thing, so my honesty doesn't really factor in.

Answer (score 3):

The story of the Garden of Eden is only 3 chapters in Genesis. These should be read thoroughly, for as Walter Bruggeman said, one cannot over interpret them.

In a plain reading, however, the sense is that there was no one other than Adam and Eve. The idea that there were others has no basis and nothing to suggest itself.

Indeed, Adam was alone, and God found it good to make him a companion, per Genesis 2.

Adam had a job - namely to name the animals and steward the Garden. These were jobs that could be done alone.

Adam also had free access to God's undivided presence, which human terms (prior to the idea of omnipresence) would have implied aloneness.

Expulsion from the Garden was inherently an act of exile from the known populated to the unknown. God speaks of the ground and the brambles, but not of other people. As an angel of the Lord was placed to keep anyone from entering the Garden, one can presume the Garden itself was depopulated of humans

In contrast, when Cain goes into exile, he does fear that others would kill him, which would lead one to suspect that Adam was at least unaware of other people.

In short, while your theory is novel, it is completely unsupported by the text.

Comment: I'm convinced that my theory is absolutely real. Otherwise, things described there have no sense. Even so, I accept that I might be wrong (a very small possibility).

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Are you hear to learn about Christianity's views or soapbox your own? (Note this isn't even about truth -- this site isn't for determining that.) All this site is good for is learning about Christianity's views and coming to understand all the doctrines, beliefs and practices of Christianity. This answer accurately summarizes a Biblical and Christian view. There are various divergent minority views but your question is not focused on those, you asked a very general one and got a very good general answer. If that's a problem, you might be asking questions for the wrong reason.

Comment: @Caleb: the answer doesn't explain at all the biblical events. I accept that it's a good try and I appreciate this.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Then edit your question to **ask about a specific event**. (And be prepared to accept an answer that represents Christianity's take on that event.)

Comment: @Caleb: do you think it's a good question to ask something like "Was Adam black or white?"? For me it would be a good question!

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Not really. First of all it's completely speculative since we aren't told much about it in Scripture and there isn't much history that speaks to the issue. Also, why would it matter? If you could connect it why it matters to you AND frame it in a way that is not seeking a factual "truth" answer but asking for what if anything Christianity teaches about the issue, then maybe.

Comment: @Caleb: It's very simple. This detail emphasizes my theory related to the fact that ouside the Garden of Eden were other people. Then where all the human races come from? All I say here is related to my previous questions. Adam should have been in one of the four primary races.

Comment: @chris's sister Fundentamentally, you view scripture as something to guide your imagination. Fundamentally, I see it as a love letter. Your objective seems to conjure up your own world, mine seeks to understand the world as it is, then extrapolate what I do not understand from it. I would suggest that your approach, while perhaps initially  more fun, will  ultimately less fulfilling.

Comment: @Affable Geek: I consider myself a rational person. I also try to understand the world as it is, but sometimes you need to use more your imagination in order to get where you want to.